# Remove Heroku completely

Tags: git, heroku, command-line, uninstallation, foreman

Can you tell me how to remove heroku account and apps from computer as well as from their website completely. I want to start from scratch as heroku command-line client is giving me unknown errors, Just tell me the way to remove/uninstall heroku and all its stuff like foreman, git etc etc from my windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To uninstall the tools that the heroku tool belt installed on your computer:

1. Open start menu
2. Search for "uninstall"
3. Click on Uninstall a Program
4. Uninstall Git, Heroku, Ruby.

Make sure that the configuration files that the tool belt used have been removed by opening "~\", showing hidden files then deleting the folder called .heroku (if it still exists).

Apps can be removed from heroku by going to the site clicking on the app in your app list, going to advanced and pressing delete app.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed using :

```
$ sudo snap install --classic heroku
```

uninstall using :

```
$ which heroku
/snap/bin/heroku
$ sudo rm snap/bin/heroku
$ heroku --version
heroku : command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Also remove all heroku gems, with something like `gem uninstall heroku --all`

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed using :

```
$ sudo snap install --classic heroku
```

uninstall using :

```
$ sudo snap remove heroku
```

Comment: this is the only way it finally uninstalled for me.